# Android: Shared transition only opens activity without animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition

I want to create a shared transition for my app, but it doesn't work like it should. It should make that fancy animation before the next activity appears, but it only opens it. And the image doesn't show there too. I have this code:

```
 public void loadContent(final List<Post> posts){
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(posts, new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostViewActivity.class);

                    ImageView placeImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.postPhoto);
                    TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textText);

                    Pair<View, String> imagePair = Pair.create((View) placeImage, getString(R.string.transition_image));
                    Pair<View, String> holderPair = Pair.create((View) textView, getString(R.string.transition_username));

                    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, imagePair, holderPair);
                    //ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, holderPair);
                    ActivityCompat.startActivity(MainActivity.this, intent, options.toBundle());
                }
            });
            RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.post_list);
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager lm = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
            rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    });
```

And these two XML files:
id:orientation="vertical"
                >

```
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:paddingTop="0px"
                android:id="@+id/postPhoto"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:id="@+id/usernameText"
                    android:transitionName="@string/transition_username"/>
```

And the other XML file:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_image"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_username"/>
```

It only opens the new activity, but not with the Image and the text. I tried it also only with the image. What's wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work like it should.. - is a bad setup of question. Please, [read this section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question correspondingly. Thanks for the understanding.

Comment: Now better? :-) @Farside

Comment: yes, @user6586661, now it's more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Good! And do you know an answer for the question, @Farside ?

Comment: This blog post helped me out in setting up shared transition:
http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition